# Grub error about no such partition

Tags: grub2

I have personal computer with a dual boot operating system Ubuntu operating system and windows but I don't want that Ubuntu Operating system partition so I formatted that partition now I am getting grub rescue error and I don't want to format my window partition.

I don't want to install Ubuntu not now. is there any way to fix it without CD/USB?

Answer (score 0):

Linux is still in control of the MBR or master boot record (so-to-speak) which isn't installed on the linux partition.

All you need to do is repair it using Windows install media or windows repair disc. You don't say which Windows version your using so here's a google search for all, just check it out:

https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=repair+wiindows+boot+record&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

The MBR needs to be replaced by the Windows one. Its very unlikely to do it without a cd/usb. Messing with it in other ways could cause you more grief. Don't do that to yourself.